Pandas setting frequency in a time series dataframe
I have a data frame with monthly data and it looks like this.
            metric
date    
2021-01-01  0.822201
2021-02-01  0.845884
2021-03-01  0.868405
2021-04-01  0.866245
2021-05-01  0.861446
2021-06-01  0.859356
2021-07-01  0.864788
2021-08-01  0.868941
2021-09-01  0.875224
2021-10-01  0.868509
2021-11-01  0.859725

The inferred frequency for this data frame is None
DatetimeIndex(['2021-05-01', '2023-08-01', '2023-09-01', '2021-11-01',
               '2023-06-01', '2022-01-01', '2023-10-01', '2023-12-01',
               '2024-04-01', '2022-10-01', '2021-08-01', '2021-06-01',
               '2021-10-01', '2024-03-01', '2023-07-01', '2022-02-01',
               '2022-07-01', '2021-09-01', '2022-11-01', '2022-03-01',
               '2024-02-01', '2023-03-01', '2021-12-01', '2021-07-01',
               '2023-02-01', '2023-11-01', '2023-04-01', '2023-05-01',
               '2021-03-01', '2021-02-01', '2024-01-01', '2022-05-01',
               '2021-01-01', '2022-06-01', '2022-09-01', '2022-04-01',
               '2021-04-01', '2022-12-01', '2023-01-01', '2022-08-01'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='date', freq=None)

So , I tried to set it explicitly like this:
data.index.freq = 'MS'

But it failed with the error
ValueError: Inferred frequency None from passed values does not conform to passed frequency MS
I tried to debug if there are any missing values in the index , but it does not seem like it :
pd.date_range(data.index.min(), data.index.max(), freq='MS').difference(data.index)

Output :
DatetimeIndex([], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)


You index must be sorted, it is currently not, which triggers the error.
idx = pd.DatetimeIndex(['2021-05-01', '2023-08-01', '2023-09-01', '2021-11-01',
               '2023-06-01', '2022-01-01', '2023-10-01', '2023-12-01',
               '2024-04-01', '2022-10-01', '2021-08-01', '2021-06-01',
               '2021-10-01', '2024-03-01', '2023-07-01', '2022-02-01',
               '2022-07-01', '2021-09-01', '2022-11-01', '2022-03-01',
               '2024-02-01', '2023-03-01', '2021-12-01', '2021-07-01',
               '2023-02-01', '2023-11-01', '2023-04-01', '2023-05-01',
               '2021-03-01', '2021-02-01', '2024-01-01', '2022-05-01',
               '2021-01-01', '2022-06-01', '2022-09-01', '2022-04-01',
               '2021-04-01', '2022-12-01', '2023-01-01', '2022-08-01'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='date')

# ensure sorting
idx = idx.sort_values()

idx.freq = 'MS'

Output:
DatetimeIndex(['2021-01-01', '2021-02-01', '2021-03-01', '2021-04-01',
               '2021-05-01', '2021-06-01', '2021-07-01', '2021-08-01',
               '2021-09-01', '2021-10-01', '2021-11-01', '2021-12-01',
               '2022-01-01', '2022-02-01', '2022-03-01', '2022-04-01',
               '2022-05-01', '2022-06-01', '2022-07-01', '2022-08-01',
               '2022-09-01', '2022-10-01', '2022-11-01', '2022-12-01',
               '2023-01-01', '2023-02-01', '2023-03-01', '2023-04-01',
               '2023-05-01', '2023-06-01', '2023-07-01', '2023-08-01',
               '2023-09-01', '2023-10-01', '2023-11-01', '2023-12-01',
               '2024-01-01', '2024-02-01', '2024-03-01', '2024-04-01'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='date', freq='MS')

If you have a DataFrame, use df.sort_index(inplace=True).
It should also contain all values between the start and end:
pd.DatetimeIndex(['2021-01-01', '2021-02-01', '2021-03-01'], freq='MS')
# DatetimeIndex(['2021-01-01', '2021-02-01', '2021-03-01'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='MS')

# now March is missing
pd.DatetimeIndex(['2021-01-01', '2021-02-01', '2021-04-01'], freq='MS')
# ValueError: Inferred frequency None from passed values does not conform to passed frequency MS

Also note that that if you have a sorted index with a given frequency, shuffling or removing an internal item will remove the frequency:
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['metric'], index=idx.sort_values())

df.index.freq
# <MonthBegin>

# shuffled index
df.sample(frac=1).index.freq
# None

# missing internal indice
df.drop('2021-02-01').index.freq
# None


Yes, sorting was indeed the problem. I did do a check of missing values and that was not a problem in my case
